# How to connect to a LSP server running at some PID?

Tags: neovim, language-server-protocol

I got a LSP server and it is a binary. Now I could run that library at a certain PID. How could I connect to that server and do some testing using `vim.lsp.buf_request`?

I do not want to use `vim.lsp.start({ cmd = {'name-of-language-server-executable'} })`, because, if I am not mistaken, it will automatically run the executable and start a new process. What I am trying to do is to have the server executable already run at some PID and start a LSP client connecting to it.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly you could run a debugger against the LSP server and connect to it, if you have the source code. There's an example with vscode and Lua lsp here: https://github.com/LuaLS/lua-language-server/wiki/Developing